# How would I make this count column in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

My dataframe:

```
df1
   Col1 
    A
    B
    C
    B
    D
    E
```

I'd like to add a second column, Col2, in which each value is 1 if it's corresponding value in Col1 appears in Col1 more than once, 0 otherwise. Hence, it would look like this:

```
df2
   Col1 Col2
   A    0
   B    1
   C    0
   B    1
   D    0
   E    0
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `duplicated` to see if any values are duplicated. Make sure to check `fromLast = TRUE` too since you want to assign `1` to both occurences

```
as.numeric(duplicated(df1$Col1) | duplicated(df1$Col1, fromLast = TRUE))
#[1] 0 1 0 1 0 0
```

Or use `ave` to count the number of occurrence and convert to Boolean when occurrence is more than `1`.

```
as.numeric(ave(1:NROW(df1), df1$Col1, FUN = length) > 1) 
#FUN specifies function (length in this case)
#[1] 0 1 0 1 0 0
```

Comment: Oh, so does length = number of rows in this case?

Comment: Awesome thanks! I decided to use your first option with the duplicated function

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this, but I think the easiest to understand is if you create a second table containing the frequency data and then join it back to the original dataframe.

First create your dataframe...

```
df1 <-
  data.frame(Col1 = c("A", "B", "C", "B", "D", "E"),
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Then make the frequency table and change the values to 0 and 1 as requested...

```
library(tidyverse)
df_freq <-
  df1 %>% group_by(Col1) %>% summarise(Col2 = n()) %>% mutate(Col2 = ifelse(Col2 > 1, 1, 0))
```

Then join the frequency table back to the original...

```
df1 %>% left_join(df_freq)
```